# Having issue outputting the results of script to .txt file in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

New to scripting, currently trying to write a script that will Invoke command to every computer located within domain. My issue is I am trying to direct the output of each computer to a text file.

```
# Name: 
# Date: 02/10/2023
# Desc: Runs remote commands for every computer within domain to collect general information

#Defining variable that reads the computer names from the .txt file
$ADCS = Get-Content -Path "C:\computers.txt"

# Loop through each computer name in the list
foreach ($ADC in $ADCS) {
        
        # Run the Invoke-Command cmdlet for each computer
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ADC -ScriptBlock {

            # Write message to indicate which computer commands are being run on.
            Write-Output "Running command on $ADC"
            
            #systeminfo | find "Host Name"

            Get-computerinfo  
        
        out-file -FilePath C:\Users\aembrey\Documents\ComputerInfo.txt
        }
} | out-file -FilePath C:\Users\aembrey\Documents\ComputerInfo.txt
```

This is what I am currently working with. I have tried multiple difference ways of using Out-file and have failed to redirect the output.

I tried formatting the command like you would as a standard command

"get-computerinfo | out-file -filepath C:\Users\X\X"

But I receive "An empty pipe element is not allowed." error.
I am sure this is a simple issue, but I am stumped.
Basically just trying to get the computer info of all computers, then save it to a text file.

Comment: The `out-file` inside the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock is not doing anything but creating an empty file in the remote hosts. I assume it should be removed from there

Comment: "I am trying to direct the output of each computer to a text file." - where? On each remote machine, or on your local disk?

Comment: As aside, the output from `Get-ComputerInfo` is a large object and some of its properties are arrays which you probably will need to deal with before outputting or decide which properties of that object you're actually needing. `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Json` should also be the cmdlets you should use to export objects, not `Out-File`.